# Shellscript: dialog, variables and umask

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

Below you can see my attempt to change the umask with a shell script, covered by dialog.

Basicly I read the input from the inputbox to a variable and use that to execute it with umask to finally change it. But.. it doesn't work..

I get back the value I typed in (tested with echo), but somehow that value doesnt execute with the umask command..

```
function edit_umask(){
    dialog --clear --backtitle "Konfigurations-Tools" --title "umask ändern" \
    --inputbox "Gewünschte umask eingeben" 8 60 2>"${INPUT}"
    RESPONSE=$?
    UMASK=$(<"${INPUT}")
    case $RESPONSE in
        0) umask "$UMASK";;
        1) echo "Abgebrochen.";;
        255) echo "ESC-Taste gedrückt.";;
    esac
}
```

Comment: It works for me. Are you running this function in a script? That will change the umask in the script process, but not your original shell.

Comment: I do, yes. I'm writing a dialog script to change certain things like umask, password or IP address for the current user.

Comment: You need to run the script with `source` if you want it to change the environment of the current shell.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
#!/bin/bash

edit_umask(){
    dialog --clear --backtitle "Konfigurations-Tools" --title "umask ändern" \
    --inputbox "Gewünschte umask eingeben" 8 60 2>"${INPUT}"
    RESPONSE=$?
    UMASK=$(<"${INPUT}")
    case $RESPONSE in
        0) umask "$UMASK";;
        1) echo "Abgebrochen.";;
        255) echo "ESC-Taste gedrückt.";;
    esac
}
edit_umask
```